# Decode compressed data using node memcached

Tags: php, node.js, memcached

How can one decode data received from Memcached? In my application, NodeJS receives thedata fro memcache. I have already implemented the flow and encoding in the PHP, but I cannot decode the data in NodeJS. Here is what I receive from Memcached in NodeJS:

NCE��s�%�Gr<ʮ�p�����ggf��v���=�O�6���ٽ?

Is there a library that can unpack it or should I write it on my own somehow?

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand why the data from memcached is encrypted. Did you encrypt it before pushing it to memcached?

Comment: Yes we have compress and store the data using php memcache class.

Comment: Did you use any encryption algorithm? Can you post the PHP code you used to store data to memcache?

Comment: We did not use any of encryption algorithm. we have used basic compression method in php as like this

`Memcache::set ( "SampleKey" , "Sample value huge data" , MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED  , 2000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memcached module is does not support php compressed value to decompress

See this link 
[https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/173](http://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/173)

If we tried to stored the data using memcached module it will be store as raw data.
we have to choose another compressing techniques (Ex: snappy) to store compressed data instead of storing raw.